# printing table as HTML using python

Tags: html, python-3.x

I used HTML form to post user input, and then CGI to capture and mysql connector to send these inputs to MYSQL db. I fetch the query result successfully, but when I wanna print it back in HTML with the code below, I got a blank page. It gives no error, just says "CGI script exited OK"  Where do you think is the problem? Is it bec I use Python 3.4

```
report=cursor.fetchall()
print ('<table border="0"><tr><th>source</th><th>period</th><th>signup</th><th>donor</th><th>avg_donation</th></tr>')
print ('<tbody>')
for field in report:
    source = field[0]
    period = field[1]
    signup = field[2]
    donor =  field[3]
    avg_donation = field[4]
    print ('<tr><td>' + source + '</td><td>' + str(period) + '</td><td>' + str(signup) + '</td><td>' + str(donor) + '</td><td>' + avg_donation + '</td></tr>')
print ('</tbody>')
print ('</table>')
cursor.close()
dbconn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to print the headers before your html content. Add this before printing your table:

```
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this this helped :))